# How to move folders of certain size in command line?

Tags: bash, shell, find, mv

In my external HDD I have two partitions, one is for Mac and the other for Windows (FAT32). Since my Mac partition is almost full due to Time Machine backup, I want to move some of my old folders (in which are movies) from the Mac partition to the Windows partition. However, the FAT32 file system only allows each file less than 4GB. But my some of the folders contain files larger than 4G. I don't want to manually go through each folder , check the size and then copy & paste the folders of small size.

So my question is:

What is the command for moving all the **folders** (including the sub-directories) less than 4GB to the new partition? Does it have anything to do with the options of `mv` command?

Thanks

--- Update 12/7/2014---

I ran `find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'f="$1";set $(du -bs "$f"); \ [[ $1 -lt 4294967296 ]] && echo mv "$f" /dest-dir' - '{}' \; >> output.txt`.

The following was the first a few lines of my output:

```
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.stZBByQJc0/Render
BASH=/bin/bash
BASH_ARGC=([0]="1")
BASH_ARGV=([0]=".")
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING=$'f="$1";set $(du -bs "$f"); \\\n        [[ $1 -lt 4294967296 ]] && echo mv "$f" /Volumes/WIN_PANC/movies/'
BASH_LINENO=()
BASH_SOURCE=()
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="3" [1]="2" [2]="53" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-apple-darwin14")
BASH_VERSION='3.2.53(1)-release'
CLICOLOR=1
COLORFGBG='15;0'
```

They are not the folders I want to move. Am I doing right?

Comment: These are typical limitations of file systems, not of commands. The beast probably is not to rely on any systems builtin storage anyway for such media stuff. Get a decent external drive (usb for example), put on it a decent file system that both your systems can read and you never have such problems again.

Comment: @arkascha: modern FSs don't have such limitations. and an external drive is (usually) just as unreliable.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The problem is not the drive, but the file system. So don't blame the drive. And about "modern" file systems... what is "modern" here and what does it help? We don't know what file system the OP is using. Looking at his setup I'd expect that to be an old installation.

Comment: @arkascha: 1) I haven't blamed the drive. 2) the OP said specifically what FS he's using. 3) chill out

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Indeed the OP specified one of the two file systems involved. Which already explains the problem. I still read that you blame the drive for such problems: "an external drive is (usually) just as unreliable.". And believe me: I am cool :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `find` command to list directories that have files greater than 4GB:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; read s _ < <(du -s "$f"); \
        [[ $s -lt 4194304 ]] && echo mv "$f" /dest-dir' - '{}' \;
```

Remove `echo` before `mv` command once you're satisfied with the listing.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't state my question very clear. I just want to move all the folders (including sub-directories) of small size (less than 4G) to a new directory. Could you explain your command a little bit? I know `-type d` says I want to find directories. It also checks the sub-directories, right? Could you explain the other parts, especially those after `bash`? Thank you.

Comment: I ran `find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'f="$1";set $(du -bs "$f"); \
        [[ $1 -lt 4294967296 ]] && echo mv "$f" /dest-dir' - '{}' \; >> output.txt`. The output I see is strange to me (see my updated post). Is that right?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer at present it just echoes those folder names that have size<4GB. You can manually check size of those folders using `du -hs folder` command to verify whether this find output is correct or not.

Comment: I tried the updated command. It reports: `du: illegal option -- b
usage: du [-H | -L | -P] [-a | -s | -d depth] [-c] [-h | -k | -m | -g] [-x] [-I mask] [file ...]`. Do you mean `du -ds` instead of `du -bs`?

Comment: ok removed `-b` (on my system I had it for size in bytes). Try updated code now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following codes can do this for you (for files >4G

```
#! /bin/bash
my_files=`ls --almost-all -1v -s -A --block-size=G|sort|sed -e 's#^[0-4]*G##g' -e '$ s#.*##g'`
echo "$my_files" >> my_files.txt
while read -r file; do
echo "MOVING FILE : $file"
mv "$file"  "destination_location"
sleep 0.5
done < my_files.txt
rm -rf my_files.txt
```

Note: change your directory to where all your files to be copied are present in a **terminal**, then you can run script from the same terminal. Ensure you replace  "destination_location" with the directory you want to move the file to inside the codes. Afterwards execute script.

Note: You will have to change your directory and run the codes in each directory.